# How to compile a project outside Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, compilation

I have downloaded a project from a website. But I don‘t want to import to [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) to compile it and generate an [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file. It's not very convinient. So is there a another method to generate an APK file?

PS: the project doesn't contain the `build.xml` file. I prefer an APK file that have been signed.

Comment: What kind of build tool does the project use? Is it Maven? Is there a pom.xml file there?

Comment: I download it from google code.There is not any file for compile in the project root directroy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use and and create a `build.xml` file. Refer to the official documentation on [managing](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html) and [building](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html) projects from the command line.